# Retrieve javascript array object data where key equals a value

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array as such:

```js
 data = [
    {id:343, article:'yes', image:'ok'},
    {id:35, article:'ko', image:'twe'},
    {id:212, article:'ere', image:'efe'},
    {id:90, article:'fefe', image:'fe'}
    ]
```

I am trying to loop through the array object, then grab `id`, `article`, and `image` data where id is equal to a certain number. So for example I want to grab `id`, `article`, and `image` when id is equal to `90`.

I am able to discern the array and if the id exists as such:

```
data.forEach(function(key,value){
            if (key['id'] === 343) {
                //how to grab rest of this object?
            }
        })
```

but from there I don't know how to grab the rest of the object data.

How would I go about this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are almost there.Get the `value` from `object` based on `key`

```js
data = [
    {id:343, article:'yes', image:'ok'},
    {id:35, article:'ko', image:'twe'},
    {id:212, article:'ere', image:'efe'},
    {id:90, article:'fefe', image:'fe'}
    ]

var result={}
data.forEach(function(item){
    if (item['id'] === 343) {
    result=item;
    }
});
console.log(result.id,result.article,result.image);
```

2. You can also use [**Array.propotype.filter()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) or [**Array.prototype.find()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

```js
data = [
{id:343, article:'yes', image:'ok'},
{id:35, article:'ko', image:'twe'},
{id:212, article:'ere', image:'efe'},
{id:90, article:'fefe', image:'fe'}
]

var result = data.filter(obj => obj.id == 343);
console.log(result);


result= data.find(obj => obj.id === 343);
console.log(result.id,result.article,result.image);
```

Comment: i like it. is this quicker than looping through one by one compared to my `forEach`? suppose i have 10000 entries in my array i have to loop through...

Comment: Always **for loop** are more proficient than **for each** than **map/reduce/filter/find**. In case of if you have multiple items then it will be better to do the filter based on condition

Answer (score 0):

Use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find):

```
const item = data.find(o => o.id === 343);
```